# maven-bundle-plugin include non existing dependencies

Tags: maven, eclipse-plugin, osgi-bundle

I have a stange problem with the "maven-bundle-plugin" in a Eclipse Plugin Project.

When I compile the project, i see on the Manifest.xml, on the "Import-Package" section a lot of java packages imports for a lot of packages that doesn't exists on my classpath, for Example:

```
Import-Package: 
COM.newmonics.PercClassLoader,
android.os,
bitronix.tm,
bitronix.tm.jndi,
bitronix.tm.resource.common,
bitronix.tm.resource.jdbc,
bitronix.tm.resource.jms,
bsh,
com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.common,
com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.recovery,
com.arjuna.ats.internal.jdbc,
com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.recovery.arjunacore,
com.arjuna.ats.jbossatx.jta,
```

All of this packages don't exists on my project or in my dependencies, but maven-bundle-plugin add it to the Manifest, and I have no idea why. Any idea or suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried running the `dependency:tree` goal to see where these dependencies are potentially listed from?

Comment: Yes, and there no trace about where dependencies come.

Comment: I have the same issue. I don't even have these packages in any of my transitive dependencies. I couldn't even find out these packages in my IDE that means these are not part of my dependency tree. @Ildelian any update on this?

Answer (score 0):

The bundle plugin generates `Import-Package` for the packages that are referred to by your project. These are the packages that should be exported by other bundles, so that your bundle can use them runtime. My first guess is that your classes refer to these packages, so check your source code first.

If your project really doesn't refer to those packages, please check if your `pom.xml` has specified these packages in an `<Import-Package>` directive in the plugin configuration. Perhaps it was copy/pasted from another project?

It could also be that you have embedded dependencies in your bundle jar that refer to the packages. To find out, you can unpack your jar (e.g. using the [rjar](https://github.com/pojosontheweb/rjar) tool) and grep the class files recursively for e.g. `bitronix/tm`.